# Norm of the algebraic adjoint of a bounded linear operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $F : H \rightarrow K$.

I want to show that $\|F^T \|= \| F\|$, where  $F^T$ is the algebraic adjoint.

I have that  $\| F\|= \sup \{ | \langle Fx,x \rangle| : x\in H, \| x\|=1\}$, and $\| F\| = \| F^*\|$.

However, I'm not sure how to using the information above to show $\|F^T \|= \| F\|$.

Any hints or ideas will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is an algebraic adjoint?

Comment: It's the transpose basically. (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Could you write an expression that characterizes "transpose" or "algebraic adjoint"? Is it by chance a map from the dual Hilbert space $H^*$ to $H$?